# How to get values from function component to class component (App.js)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two components, Parent Component i.e App.js which is class component and Child Component Demo.js is the function component, where I need to pass longitude and latitude values from Demo.js to App.js. How to do it?

Files for reference is as:
1. Demo.js

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {usePosition} from '../components/usePosition';

const Demo = () => {
  // I want to pass these values in App.js (class component)
  const {latitude,longitude} = usePosition();

  console.log('Lat', latitude);
  console.log('Lon', longitude);
  return (
    <>
      {!latitude &&  <><div>Trying to fetch location...</div><br/></>}
      <code>
        latitude: {latitude}<br/>
        longitude: {longitude}<br/>
      </code>
    </>
  );
};

export default Demo
```

2. usePosition.js

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

const defaultSettings = {
  enableHighAccuracy: false,
  timeout: Infinity,
  maximumAge: 0,
};

export const usePosition = (watch = false, settings = defaultSettings) => {
  const [position, setPosition] = useState({});
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const onChange = ({coords, timestamp}) => {
    setPosition({
      latitude: coords.latitude,
      longitude: coords.longitude,
      accuracy: coords.accuracy,
      timestamp,
    });
  };

  const onError = (error) => {
    setError(error.message);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const geo = navigator.geolocation;
    if (!geo) {
      setError('Geolocation is not supported');
      return;
    }

    let watcher = null;
    if (watch) {
      watcher = geo.watchPosition(onChange, onError, settings);
    } else {
      geo.getCurrentPosition(onChange, onError, settings);
    }

    return () => watcher && geo.clearWatch(watcher);
  }, [settings]);

  return {...position, error};
};
```

Any suggestions highly appreciated... Thanks in advance

Comment: can you provide code in sandbox? or if usePosition in seperate file then you can directly use in App.js i think

Comment: If you don't mind shall I show here the code for usePosition?

Comment: the only thing is you pass function from parent to child and access from parent that's the way.

Comment: ok, mention that code also

Comment: The code for usePostion is as

Comment: Yes please see above I've edited

Answer (score 1):

> Yes. Using callback as a prop.

```
class App extends React.Component {

     gotLatLng = (lat, lng) => {
         console.log('Lat', lat);
         console.log('Lng', lng);
     }

     render(){
        return (
           <Demo passlatLng={this.gotLatLng} />
        )
     }
} 

cost Demo = (props) => {

    const {latitude,longitude} = usePosition();

    useEffect(() => {
        if(latitude && longitude){
            props.passLatLng(latitude, longitude);
        }

    }, [latitude, longitude])   

    return (
        <>
          {!latitude &&  <><div>Trying to fetch location...</div><br/></>}
          <code>
            latitude: {latitude}<br/>
            longitude: {longitude}<br/>
         </code>
       </>
    )
}
```

Comment: Can I get these values in componentDidMount of App.js, since I want it on screen loading?

Comment: I don't think that it's possible. Well, you can access it inside componentDidUpddate. But I strongly recommend using useEffect hook instead of componentDidMount or ComponentDidUpdate. Convert your App.js to a functional component.

Comment: So, you can just make App.js functional component and use usePosition hook directly in it.

Comment: Converting App.js to functional component is a bit tedious work...

Comment: Well, I don't think so, recently I converted my whole website from classes to the functional component, just take a couple of minute for one component :)

Comment: Actually I wanted lat and lon values in cdm on screen load... Didn't find any apt solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201440/discussion-between-siraj-alam-and-pranav).